# WIFI Pineapple Nano and RPi GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wifi

I just got a wifi pineapple nano, and have been a longtime raspberry pi enthusiast, so I'm super stoked to start joining the two. I've already got it connected to my Pi and have played around a bit with the setup. My specific curiosity right now is whether it's possible to write a program to perform GPIO tasks on the raspberry pi based on events occurring on a wireless LAN broadcast by the pineapple. An example would be to turn an LED on if a specific MAC address is detected, and said client is within some power threshold. My lack of knowledge at this stage is how the pineapple fits with the pi (or any other "host" for that matter).

Specifically, do I write my program (probably python, and later some html and JavaScript served over flask) and host it on the pi? If so, how does it interact with the pineapple to get the MAC address and connection power dB? If not, do I host it on the pineapple? If so, how does the program interact with the pi to utilize its GPIO pins? How would I compile my code so that the pineapple can use it? Are there modules already available that can get me most of the way to my goal?

Comment: I realize my specific example (LED from MAC address connection power) can probably be done with Scapy while connected to the LAN. However, I want to use the router aspect of the pineapple to serve specific content to my LAN clients while actuating GPIO from various network metrics.

Comment: You shouldn't limit your authentication to MAC address, MAC can be very easily and quickly spoofed. If somebody with malicious intention got access to your code, they can pose as your device and start controlling your LED. I assume you want to scale this up and automate your home wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

I don know Pineapple Nano very much, but I found, there is an API with module Tracking.
[API](https://wiki.wifipineapple.com/#!api.md) You should be able to set script which will run when client with specific MAC address connect to AP. In script you can call some method API/Flask on your Pi.

Next solution can be `gpiozero` library, which has module `pingserver` [doc](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_other.html#pingserver), 
where you can checking some URL if is online. If you set on your AP static IP addresses for clients you want to track, you can use this module to determine, if is online (connected) or offline (disconnected)
example:

```
from gpiozero import PingServer, LED
from signal import pause

client= PingServer('192.168.0.155')
led = LED(4)

led.source_delay = 60  # check once per minute
led.source = client.values

pause()
```

In this example, when client with IP address 192.168.0.155 go online, LED will turn on.

Maybe it will help you.

Peace